# Qual a diferença entre null e undefined?

Tags: javascript, null, característica-linguagem

A maioria das linguagens de programação possui um tipo "nulo" para representar a ausência de um valor. Ela pode possuir vários nomes (`null`, `nil`, `None`, etc), mas seu propósito é o mesmo (com exceção do SQL, onde [`NULL` quer dizer "desconhecido"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_tern%C3%A1ria#Aplica.C3.A7.C3.B5es_de_bancos_de_dados)). JavaScript, entretanto, possui **dois** tipos distintos: `null` e `undefined`.

Qual a diferença entre esses dois tipos? Noto que nem sempre são usados consistentemente (embora em geral também signifiquem ausência de valor), de modo que fica difícil saber quando usar um ou outro. Sei que uma variável que nunca foi atribuída é `undefined` - bem como um campo não existente em um objeto - mas sei também que é possível atribuir manualmente esse valor através de `var x = undefined;` ou `obj.foo = undefined`.

Há alguma razão, na prática, para se usar um ou outro? Ou seria melhor usar somente um deles, e esquecer que o outro existe (e se sim, qual)? Misturar os dois no mesmo programa parece tornar mais difícil tratar casos de valor ausente... Qual seria a melhor abordagem no caso em que isso está fora do seu controle? (i.e. bibliotecas/frameworks externas usam um ou outro tipo no mesmo script)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### Diferença semântica

Como já apontado nas respostas do [Calebe Oliveira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2407/qual-a-diferenca-entre-null-e-undefined/2409#2409) e do [Alexandre Marcondes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2407/qual-a-diferenca-entre-null-e-undefined/2408#2408), existe uma diferença semântica entre `null` e `undefined`: o valor `null` é utilizado para indicar a ausência de um *objeto*, enquanto `undefined` indica a ausência de um valor qualquer. A especificação explicita isso quando define os valores [`undefined`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.9) e [`null`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.11):

> #### valor undefined
>
> valor primitivo utilizado quando uma variável não teve valor atribuído

> #### valor null
>
> valor primitivo que representa a ausência intencional de um valor de objeto

<sup>(Traduções livres)</sup>

O valor retornado pelo operador [typeof](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) é consistente com isso: ele retorna `"object"` para `null`, e `"undefined"` para `undefined`. O uso de `null` na especificação também obedece a isso. Por exemplo, todo objeto possui uma propriedade interna [[Prototype]], cujo valor deve ser um objeto ou `null` – nunca `undefined`. Como mencionado pelo Calebe, as APIs do DOM também fazem uso consistente disso.

### Diferenças sintáticas

Existem ainda diferenças sintáticas entre `null` e `undefined`. Ambos são os únicos valores de seus respectivos Tipos (`Null` e `Undefined`). Porém, `null` é também um termo reservado e um literal da gramática (como `true`, `0`, `""` e `/.*/`), o [*NullLiteral*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8), enquanto `undefined` é exposto como uma [propriedade do objeto global](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3), assim como `NaN` e `Infinity`.

Além disso, `undefined` não é um termo reservado da linguagem – o que significa, por exemplo, que `var undefined = "?"` é uma construção válida. Portanto, é sempre possível criar uma variável local chamada `undefined` cujo valor não seja o primitivo de mesmo nome. Isso não é possível com `null`, `var null = "?"` gera um erro de sintaxe.  Em implementações antigas da linguagem também era possível sobrescrever o valor global `undefined`, mas isso deixou de ser permitido no ECMAScript 5, onde a propriedade `undefined` do objeto global é definida como [[Writable]]:false, o que significa que seu valor não pode ser substituído.

### Na prática

As diferenças entre `null` e `undefined` são sutis, mas devem ser levadas em consideração pelos programadores; ignorá-las pode dar origem a bugs difíceis de identificar. Na prática, sempre leve em conta o seguinte:

- Em variáveis, funções, propriedades e métodos nativos ou *host* (fornecidas pelo ambiente, como um browser) dos quais se espera um objeto como valor ou retorno, você irá encontrar `null` caso um objeto não esteja presente. É recomendável seguir essa convenção também em seu próprio código.
- Variáveis inicializadas que nunca tiveram um valor atribuído contêm o valor `undefined`. Não se esqueça que declarações de variável são sempre erguidas (*hoisted*) para o topo do seu escopo, portanto:

  ```
  foo === undefined; // true
  var foo = 10;
  foo === 10; // true
  ```
- Parâmetros nomeados de função que não são passados no momento da chamada ganham o valor `undefined`:

  ```
  (function(foo){
      foo === undefined; // true
  }());
  ```
- `undefined` é o valor retornado quando se tenta ler uma propriedade inexistente de um objeto:

  ```
  var obj = {};
  obj.foo === undefined; // true
  ```
- `null` e `undefined` são valores *falsey*, ou seja, são convertidos para `false` quando forçados para booleanos:

  ```
  if(null || undefined) { /* nunca executa */ }
  !null === true; // true
  !undefined === true; // true
  ```
- Em comparações de igualdade abstrata (`==`) entre dois valores, `null` e `undefined` são considerados equivalentes:

  ```
  null == undefined; // true
  undefined == null; // true
  ```

  Por isso, é comum comparar apenas com `null` para verificar equivalência com qualquer um dos dois:

  ```
  if(x == null) { /* x pode ser null ou undefined */ }
  ```
- Comparações de igualdade abstrata (`==`) entre `null` ou `undefined` e um valor de outro tipo sempre retornam `false`. Isso é válido inclusive para comparação com booleanos:

  ```
  null == false; // false
  undefined == false; // false
  ```
- Ao encontrar uma referência a `undefined` em um trecho de código, tenha em mente que esse não é um termo reservado e pode ter sido redefinido:

  ```
  (function(undefined){
      undefined === window.undefined; // false
  }(10));
  ```
- Quando um objeto é serializado com `JSON.stringify`, propriedades com valor `undefined` não são incluídas na saída (JSON não tem `undefined`). Portanto, se é importante ter a chave de uma propriedade na saída serializada, é melhor utilizar `null` para marcar que ela está vazia:

  ```
  var o = {foo: undefined, bar: null };
  JSON.stringify(o); // {"bar": null}
  ```
- Quando operações que implicam conversão de tipos são aplicadas em `null` e `undefined`, os resultados podem ser diferentes:

  ```
  null + 1; // 1
  undefined + 1; // NaN
  null + ""; // "null"
  undefined + ""; // "undefined"
  ```

Answer (score 14):

A principal diferença é que `undefined` é a ausência de algo na variável. Ele indica que uma variável nunca foi definida ou que alguém atribuiu `undefined` para limpar uma variável. Se você usar o `typeof` verá que o objeto indica ser do tipo `"undefined"`.

```js
var a;
console.log(typeof a);                      //resultado> "undefined"

console.log(typeof a === "object");         //resultado> false 
console.log(typeof a === "undefined");      //resultado> true
console.log(typeof a == "undefined");       //resultado> true
```

Já o `null`é um valor nulo atribuído a um objeto. É como se você dissesse que é um objeto, mas que não foi inicializado ainda ou não foi criado. Ele é usado para passar valores padrão de objetos não inicializados. Se você usar o `typeof` verá que o objeto indica ser do tipo `"object"`.

```js
var a = null;
console.log(typeof a);                      //resultado> "object"

console.log(typeof a === "undefined");      //resultado> false
console.log(typeof a === null);             //resultado> true
console.log(typeof a == null);              //resultado> true
```

Na maioria das vezes você pode testar usando `==` tanto por `undefined` quanto por `null` que não vai fazer diferença, mas se você quer se assegurar se é algo que não foi atribuído ou se é um objeto vazio deve checar usando `===` pelo tipo específico. A comparação simples (`==`) compara apenas o valor e, se preciso, converte o valor para o tipo (caso de `strings` e números) enquanto a comparação estrita (`===`) compara o tipo e o valor, sem convertê-lo, se o tipo não for o mesmo ele retorna `false`. Veja como eles se comportam entre eles:

```js
console.log(false == undefined);       //resultado> false
console.log(false == null);            //resultado> false
console.log(null == undefined);        //resultado> true
console.log(null === null);            //resultado> true
console.log(undefined === undefined);  //resultado> true
console.log(undefined === null);       //resultado> false
console.log(undefined == null);        //resultado> true

function test(val) {
    return val == null;
}
test(null);                            //resultado > true
test(undefined);                       //resultado > true
```

Você pode tirar vantagem dessa diferença quanto está verificando por parâmetros em funções e alguns deles são opcionais. Os parâmetros que não tiverem sido passados estarão com valor `undefined` e você pode aceitar um objeto vazio com `null`. Veja um exemplo:

```js
function umaFuncao(primeiro, segundo, opcional) {
     if (typeof opcional === "undefined") {
        opcional = "três";
     }
    // faz algo
}
```

Answer (score 13):

De acordo com a documentação do ECMAScript, o valor [`undefined`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.9) é utilizado quando uma variável não possui um valor. Já o [`null`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.11) é utilizado quando se quer intencionalmente dizer que há uma ausência de qualquer valor de objeto para aquela variável.

Um exemplo prático é a chamada dos métodos ou variáveis como `getElementById`, `childNodes[n]`, `parentNode`, etc., e eles retornarem `null` em algum momento. Isso significa que a propriedade chamada existe, mas não possui um valor, ou seja, não há um objeto a ela associado. Se algum método retornar `undefined`, indica que determinada propriedade não existe.

**Demonstração:**

```js
var x;

x == null            // true
x == undefined       // true
x === null           // false
x === undefined      // true (x não tem valor!)

var y = null;

y == null            // true
y == undefined       // true
y === null           // true
y === undefined      // false (y existe, e seu valor é null)

typeof x             // 'undefined'
typeof y             // 'object'
```

Exemplos extraídos do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429225/javascript-null-or-undefined).

Answer (score 7):

### Aspectos teóricos

Semanticamente, `undefined` significa "sem referência" e `null` significa "sem valor". Ou como colocado por @Calebe Oliveira, "Se algum método retornar `undefined`, indica que determinada propriedade não existe" e se ele retorna `null` "a propriedade chamada existe, mas não possui um valor". Conforme a [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_value) (tradução livre, ênfase minha):

> Na computação (em particular, na programação), **valor indefinido** é uma condição em que uma expressão não possui um valor correto, embora seja sintaticamente correta. Um valor indefinido não deve ser confundido com a string vazia, o booleano "falso" ou outros valores "vazios" (porém definidos). Dependendo das circunstâncias, uma avaliação resultante em um valor indefinido pode causar uma exceção ou [comportamento indefinido](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamento_indefinido), mas em algumas linguagens de programação valores indefinidos podem ocorrer durante o curso normal, previsível, da execução de um programa.

A linguagem JavaScript não usa esses conceitos dessa forma, dando uma definição precisa porém bastante distinta (como demonstrado na citação feita por @bfavaretto da especificação ECMAScript), e [há quem argumente](http://blog.semanticsworks.com/2011/05/semantics-of-undefined-and-null-in.html) que a semântica do `null` é você quem define, conforme sua interpretação. A razão é que - quando se trata de variáveis, a coisa é bem mais complexa - como mostra a [seção que trata de referências](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7) (tradução livre, ênfase minha):

> Uma Referência é a resolução de um *binding* nome[-valor]. Uma Referência consiste em três componentes, o valor base, o nome referido e a flag de referência "strict" (de valor booleano). O valor base é um dos: `undefined`, um objeto, um booleano, uma string, um número, ou um registro do ambiente [de execução]. Um valor base indefinido indica que **a referência não pode ser resolvida em um *binding***. O nome referido é uma string.

Ou seja, se uma expressão não se resolver em um *binding* (i.e. **a referência** não existe) seu valor base é `undefined` e seu acesso acarreta em um `ReferenceError`; se a referência exstir, mas nunca tiver sido atribuída, seu **valor** é `undefined`. Já o `null` também representa um "valor vazio", mas somente aparece quando **explicitamente** definido como tal - variáveis não inicializadas jamais terão o valor `null`.

```js
var a = 10, b = null, c;
console.log(a); // 10
console.log(b); // null
console.log(c); // undefined
console.log(d); // Uncaught ReferenceError: d is not defined
```

### Na prática

Diversos aspectos práticos foram bem abordados nas demais respostas, mas gostaria de complementá-las com as seguintes observações:

- Programaticamente, não é possível distinguir entre uma propriedade **inexistente** e uma **com valor `undefined`**:

  ```js
  var x = {};
  console.log(x.foo); // undefined
  console.log(x);     // Object {}

  x.foo = undefined;
  console.log(x.foo); // undefined
  console.log(x);     // Object {foo: undefined}

  delete x.foo;
  console.log(x.foo); // undefined
  console.log(x);     // Object {}
  ```

  ...**a menos que** se itere sobre suas propriedades (ou técnicas similares, reflexivas):

  ```js
  for ( var p in x )
      console.log(p); // Vai imprimir "foo" se x == Object {foo: undefined}
  ```

  Por essa razão, deve-se ter cuidado caso se utilize [*duck typing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) com objetos que podem possuir valores ausentes (i.e. deve-se de fato usar `null` para representar esses valores).
- Essa diferença é observada quando um objeto é **serializado** em outro formato. Por exemplo, ao montar uma requisição Ajax ou se converter para o formato JSON:

  ```js
  $.get(url, { foo:undefined, bar:null }); // http://example.com/?bar=

  JSON.stringify({ foo:undefined, bar:null }); // {"bar":null}
  ```

  Isso possui importância prática, pois o código **consumidor** do objeto serializado pode tratar diferentemente "propriedade ausente" e "valor ausente" (ex.: Python lança um `KeyError` ao consultar uma chave ausente num `dict` - mas se comporta normalmente quando a chave existe mas seu valor é `None`). Assim, se seu objeto for em algum momento transmitido a um sistema externo, é importante usar esses tipos consistentemente e/ou **normalizar** o objeto antes da serialização (conforme o comportamento desejado).
- Muitas vezes é mais **conveniente** utilizar `undefined` do que `null`, pois pode-se expressar a ausência de um valor pela simples **ausência de código**. Exemplo:

  ```js
  function teste(obrigatorio, opcionais) {
      var acc = obrigatorio;
      acc -= (opcionais.foo || 1);
      acc -= (opcionais.bar || 2);
      acc -= (opcionais.baz || 3);
      if ( acc >= 0 )
          return acc;
  }

  var resultado = teste(10, { foo:20 });
  if ( resultado ) { ... }
  ```

  A solução "semanticamente correta" seria retornar `null` no final da função (em vez de deixá-la implicitamente retornar `undefined`), além de passar os argumentos opcionais como `{ foo:20, bar:null, baz:null }`. Admitir o uso de `undefined` nesses casos torna o código mais conciso, sem nenhum efeito indesejável (a menos é claro que os resultados interajam com sistemas externos - como exposto no item acima).
- Misturar `null` e `undefined` não causa tantos problemas, na verdade tratá-los como iguais é bem fácil (como citado de passagem em todas as outras respostas, mas sem aprofundar no assunto). Às vezes não é correto testar um valor somente como "*truey*" ou "*falsey*" - pois um valor `0`, `false` ou ainda a String vazia (`""`) ainda é considerado um valor presente - de modo que um teste explícito é necessário.

  Entretanto, como o operador `==` considera `null` e `undefined` equivalentes (e a mais nada), não é necessário se testar por **ambos** caso a entrada misture os dois. O exemplo do item anterior (que poderia retornar zero como valor válido) seria reescrito como:

  ```js
  var resultado = teste(10, { foo:20 });
  if ( resultado != null ) { ... }
  // ou
  if ( resultado != undefined ) { ... }
  ```

  (a primeira opção é preferível - além de mais curto, é semanticamente mais preciso, ao menos conforme a intenção do código)

Comment: Estou pensando aqui se concordo com algumas coisas que você diz. A especificação é consistente com o que ela diz, mas não com a sua interpretação – que é ótima na prática, mas não deixa de ser uma opinião. Ah, e o caso da serialização que você citou é importante, se me permite vou incluir um exemplo disso na minha resposta.

Comment: Independente de eu concordar ou não, +1 pela bela resposta!

Comment: @bfavaretto Vou procurar uma citação que dê suporte ao que escrevi (garanto que não saiu da minha cabeça). E fique à vontade pra aprimorar sua resposta o quanto achar necessário (estou pensando em aceitá-la, pois é a mais completa dentre as presentes).

Comment: Me interessa muito essa citação, se você achar. Eu disse que a especificação *é* consistente, mas na verdade só *me parecia que era*. Vi agora, por exemplo, que `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` retorna undefined para uma propriedade que não existe, e um objeto (descritor) para as que existem. Pela definição, deveria retornar `null` – se bem que é possível argumentar a favor dessa escolha dizendo que a propriedade em si não está definida.

Comment: @bfavaretto Concordo com sua interpretação do "property descriptor". Quanto a meu argumento original, tenho de dar o braço a torcer: a semântica do "valor indefinido" tal como descrito na Wikipedia (link na resposta editada) é uma, a semântica utilizada na especificação ECMAScript é outra. E seu comportamento é bastante inconsistente IMHO (ex.: `window.nao_existe` retorna `undefined`, mas `nao_existe` lança `ReferenceError`, **ainda que** essa expressão ocorra no top level, ou seja: a *Variable Object* do código seja o próprio *Global Object*!).

Comment: Não sei se você percebeu, mas postei a [pergunta do window.window](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/2427) por causa do trecho final do seu último comentário. Esse comportamento inconsistente só ocorre porque os engines optaram por expor o objeto global, mas isso não é um requisito da linguagem.