# Como testar valores nulos em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, null

Encontrei o código seguinte, e fiquei com a impressão de que não fazia muito sentido.

```
function (data) {
    if (data != null && data !== undefined) {
        // codigo
    }
}
```

Daqui, podem acontecer três cenários diferentes:

- A função é chamada sem argumentos, tornando `data` uma variável não declarada (e resultando em erro ao avaliar `data != null`).
- A função foi chamada especificamente com argumento `null`, ou `undefined`, e nesse caso a condição `data != null` já protege o código interno, tornando a segunda condição irrelevante.
- A função foi chamada com um argumento não-nulo, e nesse passa o teste, ambas as condições são verdadeiras.

**Existe algum cenário em que faça sentido manter a segunda condição?**

Comment: não esquece de verificar `data != ""`

Comment: @alleen94 Se bem me lembro, neste caso o argumento era suposto ser um `object`, mas no caso de strings sem dúvida é necessário verificar a string vazia.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Você tem razão, não faz muito sentido. Sobre cada um dos pontos que levantou:

> A função é chamada sem argumentos, tornando data uma variável não declarada (e resultando em erro ao avaliar data != null).

Na verdade não existe esse cenário. `data` está sempre declarada dentro da função, pois é um argumento nomeado. Se você chamar a função sem passar nada, ela fica com o valor `undefined`.

> A função foi chamada especificamente com argumento null, ou undefined, e nesse caso a condição data != null já protege o código interno, tornando a segunda condição irrelevante.

Verdade, `data != null` retorna `false` se `data` for `null` ou `undefined` (e somente nesses casos).

> A função foi chamada com um argumento não-nulo, e nesse passa o teste, ambas as condições são verdadeiras.

Certo.

> Existe algum cenário em que faça sentido manter a segunda condição?

Não :) A menos que você use operador de igualdade estrita `===`, que considera tipos. Com o `==`, qualquer comparação com `null` ou `undefined` é verdadeira se o outro lado também for `null` ou `undefined`. Ou seja, são intercambiáveis com `==`. Portanto:

```
if (data !== null && data !== undefined)
```

é o mesmo que:

```
if (data != null)
```

e o mesmo que:

```
if (data != undefined)
```

Answer (score 5):

Uma *variável não declarada* é diferente de se ter o valor `undefined`.

Exemplo de uma variável não declarada:

```
var a;
alert(b); // ReferenceError: b is not defined
```

Exemplo de uma variável com o valor `undefined`:

```
var a;
alert(a); // Escreve “undefined”
```

Quando uma função é definida esperando um argumento, a variável que representa esse argumento está sempre declarada, mesmo que o seu valor seja `undefined`, e portanto a situação de erro nunca acontece. Contudo, está certo que `data !== undefined` após o teste `data != null` é irrelevante e redundante.

O exemplo seguinte já faria sentido:

```
function (data) {
    // Ambos os testes com !==
    if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
        // codigo
    }
}
```

Repare que, pela especificação da linguagem, estes dois testes são abreviados com um apenas:

```
function (data) {
    if (data != null) {
        // codigo
    }
}
```

Comment: No Javascript não tem variável não declarada e este erro. Ele vai colocar a variável não declarada como global dentro de `window` automáticamente, portanto esse erro nunca vai acontecer.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcondes Isso só é verdade em *atribuições de valor* a variáveis não declaradas. Tente usar uma variável não declarada em outra expressão qualquer, como `a + 1`, e você verá um ReferenceError.

Comment: Hmmm, nunca encontrei esse erro em Javascript, mas vou ver ... pra mim sempre esteve como `undefined` algo não declarado.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcondes É muito simples testar, rode [isto](http://jsfiddle.net/W7qd9/) com o console aberto e você verá o erro.

Answer (score 3):

A reposta rápida é: faz diferença se a pessoa não preencher e apenas chamar `function ()` sem passar parâmetro. Neste caso vai ser `undefined`. O `null` deve explicitamente ser atribuído. A versão curta do teste seria

```
if (data != null) {
    // Código
}
```

---

### Resposta completa

Segundo minha resposta na pergunta (Qual a diferença entre null e undefined)[http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2408/280] você pode ver que o `null` é um valor atribuído e quer dizer um objeto não instanciado, já o `undefined` é algo com valor não atribuído e representa um valor especial no Javascript,  a ausência de algo na variável. Ele indica que uma variável nunca foi definida ou que alguém atribuiu `undefined` para limpar uma variável. Se você usar o `typeof` verá que o objeto indica ser do tipo `"undefined"`.

```js
var a;
console.log(typeof a);                      //resultado> "undefined"

console.log(typeof a === "object");         //resultado> false 
console.log(typeof a === "undefined");      //resultado> true
console.log(typeof a == "undefined");       //resultado> true
```

Já o `null`é um valor nulo atribuído a um objeto. Ele é usado para passar valores padrão de objetos não inicializados. Se você usar o `typeof` verá que o objeto indica ser do tipo `"object"`.

```js
var a = null;
console.log(typeof a);                      //resultado> "object"

console.log(typeof a === "undefined");      //resultado> false
console.log(typeof a === null);             //resultado> true
console.log(typeof a == null);              //resultado> true
```

Na maioria das vezes você pode testar usando `==` tanto por `undefined` quanto por `null` que não vai fazer diferença, mas se você quer se assegurar se é algo que não foi atribuído ou se é um objeto vazio deve checar usando `===` pelo tipo específico. A comparação simples (`==`) compara apenas o valor e, se preciso, converte o valor para o tipo (caso de `strings` e números) enquanto a comparação estrita (`===`) compara o tipo e o valor, sem convertê-lo, se o tipo não for o mesmo ele retorna `false`. Veja como eles se comportam entre eles:

```js
console.log(false == undefined);       //resultado> false
console.log(false == null);            //resultado> false
console.log(null == undefined);        //resultado> true
console.log(null === null);            //resultado> true
console.log(undefined === undefined);  //resultado> true
console.log(undefined === null);       //resultado> false
console.log(undefined == null);        //resultado> true

function test(val) {
    return val == null;
}
test(null);                            //resultado > true
test(undefined);                       //resultado > true
```

Você pode tirar vantagem dessa diferença quanto está verificando por parâmetros em funções e alguns deles são opcionais. Os parâmetros que não tiverem sido passados estarão com valor `undefined` e você pode aceitar um objeto vazio com `null`. Veja um exemplo:

```js
function umaFuncao(primeiro, segundo, opcional) {
     if (typeof opcional === "undefined") {
        opcional = "três";
     }
    // faz algo
}
```

Comment: @bfavaretto realmente não me atentei a tal fato.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que não foi mencionado nas respostas anteriores que valores `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `NaN` , `0` , `""`, `''` são valores *falsy* em javascript, todos eles são a mesma coisa que `false`, explicado pela [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

E todos os outros valores são *truthy* em javascript, ou seja são a mesma coisa que `true`, também explicado pela [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Ex:

```
function (data) {
    if (data) { //Se data tiver um valor
        // codigo
    }
}
```