# Quando e como devo usar operador instanceof e typeof no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Quando e como devo usar operador `instanceof` e `typeof` no JavaScript?

Em um [post do Stack EN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2449264/4395789) vejo a usabilidade do `instanceof`. Porém, em outro post do [Stack EN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17108198/4395789) diz que não é necessário usar nenhum outro operador além do `typeof`. Então gostaria de ver exemplos situacionais sobre ambos operadores.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O `instanceof` e o `typeof` têm de facto maneiras de usar que se sobrepõem. Mas têm também diferenças que os tornam distintos e aplicáveis em casos diferentes.

Repara que o `typeof` dá `object` para os seguintes casos:

```
typeof (new Date())  // "object"
typeof [1, 2, 3]     // "object"
typeof {foo: 'bar'}  // "object"
```

e no caso dos exemplos em cima podes ter uma resposta mais específica com o `instanceof`:

```
(new Date()) instanceof Date // true
[1, 2, 3] instanceof Array   // true
({foo: 'bar'}) instanceof Object // true
```

Lembra-te no entanto que em JavaScript o seguinte também é válido:

```
(new Date()) instanceof Object // true
[1, 2, 3] instanceof Object    // true
```

Por isso é bom ser específico com a instancia com que se compara.

Outra utilização onde o `instanceof` é muito útil é para saber se um objeto ou classe é uma instancia/herda de outra. Repara no exemplo em baixo e nos resultados de `console.log()`:

```js
class Transporte {
  constructor(marca) {
    this.tipo = marca;
  }
}

class Carro extends Transporte {
  constructor(marca) {
    super(marca);
    this.tipo = 'Carro';
  }
}

class Mota extends Transporte {
  constructor(marca) {
    super(marca);
    this.tipo = 'Mota';
  }
}

const VW = new Carro('Volkswagen');
const Kawasaki = new Mota('Kawasaki');

console.log(VW instanceof Carro); // true
console.log(Kawasaki instanceof Mota); // true
console.log(Kawasaki instanceof Carro); // false
console.log(VW instanceof Transporte); // true
console.log(Kawasaki instanceof Transporte); // true
```

Comment: To vendo muito errado ou os dois últimos `console.log` são iguais?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam tens razão, devia ser `Kawasaki`, corrigi.

Answer (score 5):

O operador typeof sempre resulta numa string com o nome do tipo primitivo do objeto. Por exemplo, se você executar o seguinte comando:

```
var a = typeof 1;
```

A variável `a` vai ter como valor a string "number". Ou seja, se você quer executar um código caso a variável `value` seja do tipo primitivo number, você deve fazer:

```
if (typeof value === "number") {
   // ...
}
```

No caso acima, a expressão `typeof value` irá ser resolvida para uma string com o tipo de `value`, que em seguida será comparada com a string "number".

Já o instanceof resulta num booleano que indica se um objeto foi gerado (direta ou indiretamente) por uma função construtora: `obj instanceof func`.

```
function Carro(cor, nome) {
   this.cor = cor;
   this.nome = nome;
}

var foo = new Carro("preto", "ka");
var bar = "teste";

foo instanceof Carro; // retorna true
bar instanceof Carro; // retorna false
```

Portanto, se você quiser fazer um if com instanceof, deve ficar assim:

```
if (obj instanceof Carro) {
   //
}
```

já que a expressão `obj instanceof Car` vai ser resolvida para um boolean.

Note que no exemplo abaixo, o valor de retorno de typeof é "object", ou seja, o typeof nunca pode ser usado para testar se um objeto foi criado por uma determinada função construtora, mas somente para testar o tipo primitivo do objeto.

```
var foo = new Carro();
typeof foo; // retorna "object"
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 5):

O `typeof` e o `instanceof` são complementares, além de possuírem sintaxes diferentes.

O [`typeof`](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wD86y76Bb4tLZvfpMj_2X1HtE_6rYM7AcULsVZ_Z0OA/edit) verifica o **[tipo primitivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2695/como-funcionam-os-tipos-valor-e-tipos-refer%C3%AAncia-em-javascript)** de um valor, e sempre retorna uma das seguintes strings:

```
"undefined"
"boolean"
"number"
"string"
"object"
"function"
"symbol"
```

Já o [`instanceof`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-instanceofoperator) percorre a [cadeia de protótipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15239/como-funcionam-prot%C3%B3tipos-em-javascript/15247#15247) de um determinado objeto, e verifica se nessa cadeia existe referência a um segundo objeto, retornando um booleano. Isso serve para verificar se um objeto herda de outro.

Como se vê, são funções totalmente diferentes, além do fato de o `typeof` se aplicar a qualquer valor, e o `instanceof` somente a objetos. Existe alguma confusão porque o `typeof` nunca distingue o tipo de objeto (exceto no caso das funções e símbolos), e para isso é necessário utilizar o `instanceof` e/ou outras técnicas. Há ainda o caso de `typeof null === "object"`, que pode parecer confuso mas [tem explicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2407/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-null-e-undefined/2412#2412).

Aproveito ainda para esclarecer um mal-entendido da sua pergunta, quando você diz:

> Porem em outro [post do Stack EN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17108198/4395789) diz que não é necessário usar nenhum outro operador alem do typeof

Na verdade não é isso que esse post diz. Ele diz apenas que, para descobrir se um valor é uma função, é melhor usar o `typeof` do que a função `isFunction` da biblioteca underscore.